# TrueType Font Parsing in C

Tags: c, parsing, truetype

I want to read a ttf and draw a text with that font on a buffer. Even though there are libraries such as freetype, gd to do this task, I want to write my own code. Can you advice me on how to accomplish this task?

Comment: are you already familiar with font setting (Kerning, Anti-Aliasing, Serifs, Ligaturen)? I needed a long time to grok a bit of The Metafont (which is the Font System for TeX, comparable in Complexity to TTF).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you're one of the world's top experts on fonts, typography, and writing systems, the answer is simple: **DON'T**. TrueType/OpenType has a lot of tables you need to support for correct rendering, and even when using FreeType (which is an extremely low-level library), most people get it wrong.

If you need to do low-level, deterministic-across-platforms font handling, then at the very least, you should be using FreeType and libotf. This will provide you with access to the glyphs and outlines which you can then render however you like. In most cases though using your GUI system's text rendering routines will be a lot easier and less error-prone.

Finally, if you insist on ignoring my advice, a good RTFS on FreeType and Microsoft's online resources explaining the tables in TrueType/OpenType fonts are probably the best place to get started.

Comment: It is really disheartening to see answers like this. I know he accepted this answer, but still. Dude said he wants to, not that he needs to. We should encurage people to explore, learn and practise solving problems. Everyone should practise the craft, they're building a career in! Too many people only knows how to implement and use libraries, it's almost like they're afrade of solving problems themselves. It leads to bad, slow & buggy software that is helt together with duck-tape with miles long un-debuggable stacktraces.

Comment: And no. You don't need to be a "world's expert on fonts" to do what he asked.

Comment: You really do need to be an expert to do this. Otherwise you will create something that is completely incompatible with displaying text in some users' languages.

Comment: libschrift is a counter example to this answer. It is 1500 lines of C with no dependencies. It can parse TTF files and render glyphs well enough for many use cases. Its author was not one of the world's top experts on fonts.  https://github.com/tomolt/libschrift

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge: Does it process the shaping tables necessary for rendering text in scripts/languages that do not have a one-to-one correspondence between chaaracters and glyphs? If not, then it's an example of exactly what I was saying.

Comment: Just tested and confirmed it does not. The test case for the demo program seems to have been specifically chosen to feature scripts that look exotic/impressive while excluding anything that needs processing of shaping (character to glyph) mapping tables.

Comment: I think we're quite far apart on philosophy here. I like to make my software as simple as it can be. I've never needed the feature you mention, so I chose libschrift over a more fully featured library. I don't think the original questioner required that feature either. I'm pretty sure libschrift is the kind of thing the questioner wanted to write.

I'd be happier if your answer started with "If you require features x, y and z..."

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge: We share philosophy, but software can only be as simple as the requirements admit. You cannot just decide "oh, your language will display like garbled junk". Support for text in any language/script is a baseline requirement that's non-negotiable, and not that hard, but does require some serious expertise in understanding the requirements. Not just wishing them away.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you

1. Read all the TTF docs you can find
2. Find all the open source TTF parsers + renderers you can find, in many different languages, such as Freetype (c/c++), Batik (java), and anything else you can google for. Also George Williams' fontforge will likely be very helpful to you on your journey.
3. Rip apart all the programs you collected in 1. and see how they work. See if you can make a tiny small example program to do something simple, like dump the list of points for the outline of the letter "I".
4. Work on your rasterization. Start with something very simple, like rasterizing the letter "l".

The problem with TTF is that there is not a simple file format, and freetype handles a lot of crazy details for you. However if you don't care about portability, and you already have a specific TTF file you want to render, and you only care about a small simple alphabet, like Latin or Cyrillic, you might be OK.

Also you might want to check out a list of TTF documentation I linked to from my little project https://github.com/donbright/font_to_svg/

Answer (score 2):

Not impossible, for anyone else tempted to try.  I was curious about doing it because I like the DIY graphics approach where I allocate some memory and write into it, then save as a jpg or png.  I pirated a bitmap font from giflib but that's strictly 8x8 pixels.

A few links:

```
`http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=143`
`https://www.google.com/search?q=ttf+parser+c&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8`
```

Comment: The GitHub link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

as R.. wrote the same time as i did in my comment, i would not to suggest to build another TTF-parser by your own. If you are eager to learn this very "spannende" field of Computer Science I would recommend "The Art of Computer Programming" Vol 2 from Donald E. Knuth. (it is Metafont, not TTF, but proven to be correct:-)